# Rails help controller not saving param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with my controller. 
My param rating is not saved in my column rating_score.

My controller:

```
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@konkurrancer.id.to_s

    @konkurrancer.rating_score += params[:rating].to_i
    @konkurrancer.ratings += 1
    @konkurrancer.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Console log:

```
Started POST "/konkurrancers/rate/51" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-04 13:26:59 +0200

  Processing by KonkurrancersController#rate as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"v/u83R+w6WXIwqkjrHLZJxOby5/
tmOdzVGBPfBCLinI=", "vind"=>{"rating"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Gem Vind", "id"=>"51"}
  ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
ancers`
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`←
[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`cached_slug` = '51') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggab
le_type = 'Konkurrancer' AND slugs.name = '51' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 51) LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSlug Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slug
s`.sluggable_id = 51 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Konkurrancer') ORDER BY id DE
SC LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mAREL (2.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE `konkurrancers` SET `ratings` = 4, `updated_
at` = '2011-04-04 11:27:00' WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 51)
  ←[1m←[36mSlug Load (3.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slug
s`.sluggable_id = 51 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Konkurrancer') AND (`slugs`.`
name` = 'vind-et-rejsegavekort-p├Ñ-helt-op-til-25000-kroner-lige-her') AND (`slu
gs`.`scope` IS NULL) ORDER BY id DESC←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mAREL (2.0ms)←[0m  DELETE FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slugs`.`id` = 82)
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slugs`.`nam
e` = 'vind-et-rejsegavekort-p├Ñ-helt-op-til-25000-kroner-lige-her') AND (`slugs`
.`scope` IS NULL) AND (`slugs`.`sluggable_type` = 'Konkurrancer')←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (27.0ms)←[0m  describe `slugs`
  ←[1m←[36mAREL (54.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO `slugs` (`name`, `sluggable_id`, `
sequence`, `sluggable_type`, `scope`, `created_at`) VALUES ('vind-et-rejsegaveko
rt-p├Ñ-helt-op-til-25000-kroner-lige-her', 51, 1, 'Konkurrancer', NULL, '2011-04
-04 11:27:00')←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSlug Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slugs`.s
luggable_id = 51 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Konkurrancer') ORDER BY id DESC L
IMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (13.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
Rendered konkurrancers/_rating.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered konkurrancers/rate.js.erb (19.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 417ms (Views: 183.0ms | ActiveRecord: 107.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rating is being passed in as a parameter in the following format:

```
params[:vind][:rating]
```

Change the relevant line in your controller from `params[:rating]` to `params[:vind][:rating]` and it should work.

Comment: Is it because the param rating is inside the param vind?

Comment: Yes it is. Using the `form_for` method on an `@object` will result in all the attributes being contained in a params hash of the object name.